# Incorporating more than 20 predictors in residuals vs predictor plot using ggResidpanel

Tags: r, regression

I am using the resid_xpanel() function in ggResidpanel to look at plots of regression model residuals vs predictor variables. I have 23 predictor variables in my model and I had used the basic code:

library(ggResidpanel)

resid_xpanel(mymodel)

Through this the plots look very squished like so:

[Residuals vs predictor variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KxeMb.png)

Is there any modification to the code that will incorporate 23 plots (for 23 predictor variables) more clearly? I have repeated this with just 3 predictor variables and naturally the plots were much bigger and more evenly spaced out. Instead of plotting them one by one, I thought this package made it faster by using just one line of code, hence my preference for not coding the plots one by one.

Thank you!

Comment: Might want to look into changing the point size to be smaller and transparent, + graphing the 0-1 xaxis variables separately so that you can remove the space beneath.

Comment: @EvanFriedland Would you have any suggestions as to how to modify the code to incorporate point size, transparency, and graphing the variables separately? The only options I have in resid_xpanel function are for scaling (which scales all graphs but then they get cut off) and nrow (which is for the # of rows but that also doesn't allow proper full size graphs). I have played around with the text size so that's fine. Maybe it's because I am using an R Markdown file to write my code?